# $.when(ajaxCall) Versus success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code inside my asp.net MVC view:-

```
$('body').on("click", "#transferserver,#transfersd,#transferfirewall,#transferrouter,#transferswitch", function () {

        $("#showoptions").dialog({
            title: "Assign Selected Records To New Rack",
            width: 'auto', // overcomes width:'auto' and maxWidth bug
            maxWidth: 600,
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            fluid: true, //new option
            resizable: false
        });

        var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Rack/ShowTransferSelectedDialog")',
            data: {
                rackfrom: "@Model.Rack.ITsysRackID",
                assettype: $(this).attr('id')//get the id for the clciked link, so that the submit button will call the associted action method.


                },
            type: 'get',
            success: function (html) {
                $('#showoptions').html(html);
                $("#showoptions").dialog("show"); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.
            }
        });
        $.when(ajaxCall)
.then(function (data) { showDialog(data); });
    });
```

I have the following questions:

1. What are the differences between the `$when(ajaxcall)` and on success ?
2. In my above code if I remove the `$.when(ajaxCall)` the dialog box will still be displayed . so is there any need to have it?

Thanks

**EDIT**
But one benefit i find for using `$.when(ajaxCall)` is that i have defined a custom authorization attribute as follow:-

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]

    public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {


        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                var viewResult = new JsonResult();
                viewResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
                viewResult.Data = (new { IsSuccess = "Unauthorized", description = "Sorry, you do not have the required permission to perform this action." });
                filterContext.Result = viewResult;

            }

        }
    }
```

currently if the user clicks on the link to display the dialog box and he is not authorize to do so ,  he will receive a jAlert containing the unauthorized message as follow:-
![enter image description here][1]

but if i remove the     `$.when(ajaxCall),` then the user will not receive the unauthorization message , and instead the dialog will be blank .. so can anyone advice ?

Comment: No, you don't need `$.when` for a single ajax call, and you should replace `.then` with `.done`.

Comment: You either use the success callback OR use ajaxCall.then(...). Don't use both at the same time. The benefit of using ajaxCall.then is that you can chain it with other ajax-calls and easier handle failures like `ajaxCall.then(function(data) { return $.getJSON("/test.json?val=" + data.val) }).then(function(testResponse) { ... }).fail(/* error handler */).always(/* always execute this code no matter if something fails or not */)`

Comment: @adeneo why i should use .done instead of .then ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this case, but `then` is more like the deprecated `pipe`, and all you really need here is to chain on a success handler, which is commonly done with `done`, so it's more intuitive to use that in my opinion, but again, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

1) This is the definition of jQuery [`when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

It make no sense to use it for a single ajax call, you want to use it for 2 or more so you wait for them to finish before executing some code.

2) I don't know what `showDialog` does but your dialog already shows because in your `success` handler you have `$("#showoptions").dialog("show");`. Again, no need at all to use `when` here

Comment: can you check my edit, as if i remove the when , the it will cause some problems in my case

Comment: here is the showDialog code function showDialog(data) {
    if (data.IsSuccess == "Unauthorized") {

        jAlert(data.description, 'Unauthorized Access');
    }
}

Comment: @john G: I'm confused... `html` parameter (on suceess handler) and `data` (on then handler) must be the same. Why one is an html and the other is a json object?

Comment: The custom authorization class will return json if the request is unauthorized, which it is a general function. so the server might return html or json, etc . now for this function the action method will return an html to render inside the dialog box, but if the user is not authorized then he will receive the unauthorized message (defined inside the authorization class) and my  $.when(ajaxCall) will handle displaying the unauthorized code,, so in my situation the  $.when(ajaxCall) is mandatory , otherwise the user will not receive any unauthorized message. what do u think/

Comment: @john G: does your handler returns status 401 when unauthorized? If this is the case (and you should), you could just use the `fail` handler on ajax call to handle failure.

Comment: no i am returning all "200 ok" even when the request is unauthorized, but i display an error message accordingly .

Comment: @johnG: try checking on your success handler if parameter is a json object or a string and do correct action in every case (`if (typeof html === 'object') <-- then received a json object`. In any case I think your not implenting it well, it's a little mess :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i know that my approach is weak ,, but can you advice how i can improve it. i am think of returning 401 http response from my custom authrization class instead of returning json object , and to handle all the 401 ajax requests at one place?